# Cropping and centering wide images

Tags: css

How would I automatically crop the image in a gallery preview so that the wide image is cut off on left and right? Showing exactly the center part of the image as in this attached picture:

[image: crop and center wide image]

I have this structure:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100px; width: 120px;">
    <div class="container">
        <img />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to do this only with CSS and no javascript.
Negative margin (fixed) isn't posible because the width of my pictures can be very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually use is the following:

```css
.container {
  height: 100px; 
  width: 120px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x350" />
</div>
```

This works with any image size. You could even add a height to the image to limit its height (like in your image) to your containers height (then it would only cut the left and right sides of the image). You can use this for any element, including `video`.

Comment: Works! With with a small addition ("height: 100%" to image - for stretching) Cool.
Thanks!

Comment: @Maxick I did mention you should add height to accomplish a result similar to your image. I usually use this code to stretch a background video (if you set `min-width` and `min-height` to 100% it is nicely covering the whole area)

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning with high negative left and right values.
This combined width `margin: 0 auto` will center the image in the container letting the left and right parts overflow :

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  left:-100%; right:-100%;
  height:100%; width:auto;  
  margin:0 auto;  
}
/*** FOR THE DEMO ***/
div{margin:0 auto;border:1px solid red;overflow:visible;}img{z-index:-1;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way is to make the image a background image and center it like [in this example](http://codepen.io/arjabbar/pen/NxXBKK).

Basically set the background image where your `.wrapper` div is like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url(/images/your-image.jpg)">
</div>
```

After you do this, the class `wrapper` wouldn't make much since, but you can change it to something like `preview` or `thumbnail`.

And then your styling would look like this:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 120px; //Or whatever width you need it to be.
  height: 100px;  //Or whatever height you need it to be.
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

This does use a little inline styling, which some people frown upon, but it does work and it's simple.

Comment: How is this wrong? Explanations would be nice that way I can correct my problems.